# Vuejs open same page on two different routes issue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to open the same page but by using two different routes. The issue is when clicking on link 1 and after that click on link 2 my page is not being refreshed, when I print this.$route it shows old route info. How to solve this issue?

Link 1 - http://localhost:8080/test1route
Link 2 - http://localhost:8080/test2route

```
import TestComponent from '@/Component/TestComponent'
export default [{
    path: '/test1route',
    component: TestComponent,
    children: [{
        path: '/',
        component: () => import('@/List')
    },
    {
        path: '/test2route',
        component: () => import('@/List')
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your route definition, the path to Link2 would actually be http://localhost:8080/test1route/test2route, since 'test2route' is a child of 'test1route'.

Comment: "Note that nested paths that start with / will be treated as a root path. This allows you to leverage the component nesting without having to use a nested URL" - https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html